# AJAX call working on local server but not online

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When a user goes to one of the pages (let's call it *page1*), the PHP loads the HTML content for an array containing data about the users.

Once the page is loaded (DOM ready), I use *jQuery* to perform an *AJAX* call to retrieve the HTML for that array of data. I do this to get the benefit of using separate PHP template files. In this way, PHP will call the PHP template for every array in the bi-dimensionnal array and return the HTML.

**page1.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalArray = <?php echo json_encode($freres); ?>;

    jQuery(function($) {
        liste(); // Ajax call to get HTML for the data in "globalArray"
    });
</script>
```

**AJAX call:**

```
function liste() {
    $.ajax({
        data : {
            array : globalArray,
            dataName : 'someName',
            file : 'templates/t_item_file'
        },
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var table = $('table');
                var rows = $('<table>' + data + '</table>').find('tr');

                rows.each(function(i, e) { // insert with fade-in animations
                    var row = $(e);

                    row.hide();
                    table.append(row);
                    row.delay(i * 15).fadeIn(250);
                });
        },
        type : 'GET',
        url : config.site + 'ajax/view' // configured in header
    });
}
```

Somewhere in **t_header.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        base : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>",
        site : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>"
    };
</script>
```

The config route that redirects to **ajax/view/...**

```
$route['ajax/(:any)'] = 'c_ajax/$1';
```

**The method of the controller c_ajax** that handles the AJAX call:

```
public function view() {
        $file = $this->input->get('file');
        $array = $this->input->get('array');
        $dataName = $this->input->get('dataName');

        foreach ($array as $vars) {
            $data[$dataName] = $vars;

            $this->load->view($file, $data);
        }
    }
```

When I do this using *EasyPHP* on localhost, everything works fine, and I receive the HTML as expected, something like :

```
<TR>
    <TD>...</TD>
    //...
</TR>
<TR>
//...
```

And then I insert it into a `table`. But, when I try to do it on my website in FireBug, I can see that the AJAX response is not `200`, but `302 Moved Temporarily`.

Can anyone help me to figure out what to do to get it to work, because I spend almost the last four days learning jQuery and AJAX, and it doesn't work (online only).

Comment: `302` is a redirect, probably unrelated to your actual code. Look for `.htaccess` files (assuming Apache) that define redirects, or what you have created in code.

Comment: try to hit ajax url in your browser directly into address bar check what you are getting

Comment: @hexblot Indeed I have a .htaccess at the root of my server that handle that set PHP_5_4 and one other at the root directory of my CodeIgniter hierarchy to remove the `index.php` from the URL. I already tried to remove it and put back the *index.php* in the URL but it's still not working.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Yes good idea, I tried and it redirects me to my connexion controller and seems to *destroy* the session because I then have to log in again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. I load the HTML data in PHP and pass it to JavaScript, and then use jQuery to animate DOM Elements.

Previously, I didn't pass HTML but raw data in a PHP array, and then tried to get the HTML for all the elements of thie array via Ajax (HTML for all elements in only one call). I think there was too many parameters in the request and that's probably was caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

file : 'templates/t_item_file'

give full path of the controller

eg:"http://www.yourdomain.com/---/templates/t_item_file"

Comment: As you can see in the `view()` method I load the template using the CI load object so I don't think this is the problem, because the file is located in *views/templates/t_item_file*.